# Mostrar fecha literal basada en fecha tipo base de datos (date) PHP

Tags: php

Tengo esta fecha en mi base de datos:

> **2020-10-10 ó 2020-10-10 10:00:30**

Y quiero mostrarla en este formato español:

> **10 de Octubre del 2020**

Desearia hacerlo con una funcion php

Comment: Y que has intentado?, Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y puede terminar cerrada

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la respuesta, si pueden simplificarla o mejorarla les agradeceria mucho

```
function clearDateShow($date=null){
$meses = array("","Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
if($date && strlen($date)==10){
$date_2=explode("-",$date);
return $date_2[2]." de ".$meses[(int) $date_2[1]]." del ".$date_2[0];
}
}

echo clearDateShow("2020-10-10");
```